# logic on join two tables and using sum formula

Tags: sql

Need some help with the logic for SQL join

Table1

- CustomerID (ex.1234123)
- Customer_name (ex.string)

Table 2 
 - CustomerID (ex.1234 but has it multiple times in the column)
 - products (dog food, cat food, etc on different rows within the same column)
 - revenue for product

How do join two tables together when one table has multiple rows of data that aggregates into one ID with one row of data.

Row 
CustomerID ---- Customer_name-------dog food (revenue)------cat food (revenue)

Hope this makes sense and google searching this nonsense didnt really find what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select   c.customerid,
         C.Customer_name,
         sum(case when product = 'dog food' then revenue else 0 end) as dog_food_rev,
         sum(case when product = 'cat food' then revenue else 0 end) as cat_food_rev
from     table1 c
    join table2 p
      on c.customerid = p.customerid
group by c.customerid, c.Customer_name
```

This assumes the revenue field is named REVENUE

Also assumes that the product values are entitled 'dog food' and 'cat food' exactly (rename as necessary)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/413cb/4)

Comment: So I have a small table that needs to extract data from a big table. There are 50 rows in the small table and millions of rows in the big table. I want to only use the small table but only need the data from the big table to populate the small tables ID. If this makes any sense.

Comment: @user3802773 sounds like you want to write an update statement that updates the small table's data using data in the big table. Can you create another question w/ the details?

Comment: awesome tool SQL Fiddle! Thank you all with the help from you guys I was able to find a solution. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Pivoting the table

```
Select CustomerID, Customer_name, IsNull([Dog Food],0) [Dog Food], IsNull([Cat Food],0) [Cat Food]
from (
  select A.*, B.product, B.Revenue
  from Table1 A
  inner join Table2 B
     on A.CustomerID = B.CustomerID
) A
 pivot (sum(revenue) for product in ([Dog Food],[Cat Food])) B
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/413cb/2)

Answer (score 0):

You do this with a join and conditional aggregation:

```
select t1.customerid,
       t1.Customer_Name,
       sum(case when product = 'dog food' then revenue else 0 end) as DogFood,
       sum(case when product = 'cat food' then revenue else 0 end) as CatFood
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.customerid = t2.customerid
group by t1.customerid, t1.Customer_Name
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/413cb/5)